# How to watch the directory with multiple files changes using inotify in c

Tags: c, inotify

I have a some 50 files which is moved to a directory "/tmp" on some interval of time when its get modified. I am using inotify to watch this directory /tmp for these files moved to this directory so that I can merge these files to another file in another directory.

But the rate at which the files getting moved to this directory ("/tmp"), inotify is not able to give notifications for other files except one file.

How to watch the directory if multiple files with different names (unknown names) being created or moved to the directory using inotify.

I know I can create multiple watch discriptors for each file with its name . 
But I dont know the file name which is getting created or moved to this directory.  Dynamically the files gets created so I cannot create watch descriptors for each file.

Below is my code.

How can I check notifications for the multiple files gettign created in this directory.

Please help with the solution. 
Your help is highly appreciated. 
Thanks

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    int length, i = 0;
    int fd;
    int wd;
    char buffer[BUF_LEN];

    fd = inotify_init();

    if ( fd < 0 ) {
        perror( "inotify_init" );
    }

    wd = inotify_add_watch( fd, "/tmp/", IN_MOVED_TO);


    while (1){
        struct inotify_event *event;

        length = read( fd, buffer, BUF_LEN );

        if ( length < 0 ) {
            perror( "read" );
        }

        event = ( struct inotify_event * ) &buffer[ i ];

        if ( event->len ) {
           if ( event->mask & IN_CREATE || IN_MOVED_TO) {
                printf( "The file %s was created.\n", event->name );

            }
        }
    }
    ( void ) inotify_rm_watch( fd, wd );
    ( void ) close( fd );

    exit( 0 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To monitor a directory for file creation or deletion, you can create an `inotify` instance and monitor with the flags `IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE`. To monitor a file or directory, you first create the `inotify` instance with `inotify_init` which will return a file descriptor. You can then add files/directories to monitor with `inotify_add_watch` and supply the proper flags to look for the desired changes. You can then simply use `read` which will block until changes meeting you criteria are detected.

A simple example to monitor a directory (given as input as the first argument [`./tmp` default]) is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>

#define EVENT_SIZE  ( sizeof (struct inotify_event) )
#define EVENT_BUF_LEN     ( 1024 * ( EVENT_SIZE + 16 ) )

int dir_exists (char *d);

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int length, i = 0;
    int fd;
    int wd;
    char buffer[EVENT_BUF_LEN];
    char *path = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "./tmp";

    /* check directory to monitor exists */
    if (!dir_exists (path)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: directory does not exist '%s'.\n", path);
        return 1;
    }

    /* create inotify instance & validate */
    if ((fd = inotify_init ()) < 0) {
        perror ("inotify_init");
    }

    /* add path to inotify watch list monitor for file create, delete.
       add IN_MOVED_FROM | IN_MOVED_TO or move to/from directory */
    wd = inotify_add_watch (fd, path, IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE);

    /* monitor path for new file creation or deletion
      (read blocks until the change event occurs) */
    if ((length = read (fd, buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN)) < 0) {
        perror ("read");
    }

    /* report name of file created or deleted  */
    while (i < length) {
        struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *) &buffer[i];
        if (event->len) {
            if (event->mask & IN_CREATE) {
                if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR) {
                    printf ("New directory %s created.\n", event->name);
                } else {
                    printf ("New file %s created.\n", event->name);
                }
            } else if (event->mask & IN_DELETE) {
                if (event->mask & IN_ISDIR) {
                    printf ("Directory %s deleted.\n", event->name);
                } else {
                    printf ("File %s deleted.\n", event->name);
                }
            }
        }
        i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
    }
    /* remove monitoring of path from the watch list. */
    inotify_rm_watch (fd, wd);

    /* close the inotify instance */
    close (fd);

    return 0;

}

/** test that directory exists (>=1 success, 0 otherwise)
 *  NOTE: no directory is actually created. fail occurs instead.
 */
int dir_exists (char *d)
{
    int flags = O_DIRECTORY | O_RDONLY;
    int mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR;
    int fd = open (d, flags, mode);

    if (fd < 0)     /* directory does not exist */
        return 0;
    else if (fd) {  /* directory exists, rtn fd */
        close (fd);
    }

    return fd;
}
```

**Compile**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/inotify_watch inotify_watch.c
```

**Example Use**

```
$ ./bin/inotify_watch &
[1] 16916

$ touch tmp/file.txt
New file file.txt created.
[1]+  Done                    ./bin/inotify_watch
```

Answer (score -1):

Use functions FindFirstFile and FindNextFile. For example, show this code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <io.h>
/*
HANDLE FindFirstFile
(
    LPCTSTR lpFileName,     // какой файл ищем, можно указывать маску *, ?
    LPWIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData    // указатель на структуру с информацией
);*/
//В случае ошибке вернет INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE. Для продолжения поиска используется функция:
/*
BOOL FindNextFile
(
    HANDLE hFindFile,           // указатель на поиск 
    LPWIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData    // указатель на структуру с информацией
);*/


//Write this any address
#define DISK "C:\\"
void main()
{

    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hf;
    struct stat st;

    hf=FindFirstFile(DISK"*", &FindFileData);

    if (hf!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            char s[MAX_PATH] = DISK;
            int a;

            strcat(s, FindFileData.cFileName);
            stat(s, &st);
            a = access(s, 04);
            printf("%s\t\t%s\n", FindFileData.cFileName, st.st_mode & S_IFDIR ? "Directory" : (st.st_mode & S_IFREG ? "File" : "Other"));
        }
        while (FindNextFile(hf,&FindFileData)!=0);
        FindClose(hf);
    }

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Hi Konstantin Dedov, thanks for the reply. But I am looking for something like this function in C on linux platform. windows code will not help me much.